# Remove items in a list that don't have a character in a specified position in the list

Tags: java, list, search

I am trying to make a program that takes a file of strings and refines the list to the string I am looking for. I can get all the strings in the file into a list, but I can't seem to search for a character in a specified position in the string. Is that even possible?

I have a file named "phrase" that contains

```
beat_the_rap
have_a_nice_day
book_learning
head_of_the_class
```

If I enter a 'b' at position 1, nothing gets removed from the list.

[here is my code so far](http://ideone.com/lT5EHV)

```java
package sharkattack;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Reader;

/**
 *
 * @author Mav
 */

public class SharkAttack {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @param position the place in the string the user wants
     * @param userChar the character the user is going to check
     * @param s the scanner to find the file
     * @param category the name for the file to be found
     * @param cs i don't really know
     * @param list the list of all the items in the file
     */
    static int position = 0;
    static char userChar = 0;
    public static Scanner s;
    static String category = "";
    static CharSequence cs;
    static ArrayList<CharSequence> list;


    public static boolean getCategory()
    {
        try
        { s = new Scanner(new File("strings/" + category + ".txt")); }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void printList()
    {
        list.stream().forEach
            (
             (list1) ->
             {
             System.out.println(list1);
             }
            );
    }

    public static void fillList()
    {
        list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SharkAttack sh = new SharkAttack();
        cs = new CharSequence()
        {
            @Override
            public int length() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
            @Override
            public char charAt(int i) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
            @Override
            public CharSequence subSequence(int i, int i1) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };

        Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the category?");
        category = file.next();


        if (sh.getCategory() == true)
            System.out.println("Found file: " + category);
        else
            System.out.println("No file found");


        sh.fillList();
        sh.printList();

        //==============================PROBLEM HERE===================================
        Scanner pos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a correct letter");
        userChar = pos.nextLine().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("At what position in the string?");
        position = pos.nextInt() - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i).charAt(position) != userChar)
            {
                System.out.println(list.remove(i) + " did not match");
            }
        }
        sh.printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: First indent your code. Respect volunteers here.

Comment: If the file is named "phrase" and not "phrase.txt" then your list is empty. You probably should use a debugger and narrow down the issue